# How do I split a string with multiple separators in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

How do I split a string with multiple separators in JavaScript?

I'm trying to split on both *commas* and *spaces*, but AFAIK JavaScript's `split()` function only supports one separator.

Comment: I had this problem trying to split up file paths that were constructed with nodejs under windows. There were forward "/" and back "\" slashes in the same path sometimes.

Answer (score 991, accepted):

Pass in a regexp as the parameter:

```
js> "Hello awesome, world!".split(/[\s,]+/)
Hello,awesome,world!
```

**Edited to add:**

You can get the last element by selecting the length of the array minus 1:

```
>>> bits = "Hello awesome, world!".split(/[\s,]+/)
["Hello", "awesome", "world!"]
>>> bit = bits[bits.length - 1]
"world!"
```

... and if the pattern doesn't match:

```
>>> bits = "Hello awesome, world!".split(/foo/)
["Hello awesome, world!"]
>>> bits[bits.length - 1]
"Hello awesome, world!"
```

Comment: What are you using for your js> console?

Comment: rhino, Mozilla's implementation of JavaScript in Java: http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/ (... or "sudo apt-get install rhino").

Comment: thanks. another question related to this
what i need to do is get the last element of the splitted array. if there's no array it should return the string
thx

Comment: Is there any way to avoid removing the separators when splitting with a regular expression?

Comment: How to split for both a string "hello world" as well as another character (or other regex), like the pipe symbol? Tried variations of `(hello world)|\|` which didn't quite work yet. Any ideas?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty not sure if you still need this to work, but a string works just fine. Your pattern wasn't wrong, but maybe your string had no matches or something? Try this string: `"hey guess what?hello world: it's my birthday|never say never"` and then match with this pattern `/(hello world|\|)/g` (don't forget the `/g` for multiple hits). I get two matches when I run this into a regex checker. Give it a try.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Use capturing parentheses around the separators in the regex, as [explainded here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split#Capturing_parentheses). `"Hello awesome, world!".split(/([\s,]+)/)` => `["Hello", " ", "awesome", ", ", "world!"]`

Comment: Why is the `+` required in your first two examples? Seems to work fine without. With the + you will end up skipping over blanks e.g. two spaces / commas in a row with nothing in between, which has the potential to mask errors.

Comment: lets say i want to split it with 'and', '&', '/s', '-' how will you do that, it's not working for 'and' keyword. it is matching with 'a', 'n','d', i want to match with whole word 'and'. any suggestions

Comment: simple way use split(/\W/)

Comment: Right in the spot!!!

Answer (score 351):

You can pass a regex into JavaScript's [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method. For example:

```js
"1,2 3".split(/,| /) 
["1", "2", "3"]
```

Or, if you want to allow **multiple separators** together to act as one only:

```js
"1, 2, , 3".split(/(?:,| )+/) 
["1", "2", "3"]
```

You have to use the non-capturing `(?:)` parenthesis, because
otherwise it gets spliced back into the result. Or you can be smart
like Aaron and use a character class.

Examples tested in Safari and Firefox.

Comment: If you need multiple characters to act as one, as in, say "one;#two;#new jersey", you can simply pass the string ";#" to the split function.  "one;#two;#new jersey".split(";#")[2] === "new jersey"

Comment: This method works better than character classes if you need to split on more than one character. Separate them by `|` as Jesse shows.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to avoid removing the separators when splitting a string with a regular expression: this example removes the separators, but I hope it's possible to split a string without removing them.

Comment: @AndersonGreen It depends on exactly what you want; in this case, there are multiple separators, so do you want to keep them all? As a separate item? Joined to the previous item? Next item? It seems unclear to me. You might want to make a new question with some examples of what you're looking for.

Comment: @JesseRusak I meant keeping all of the separators as separate items, so that a string could be tokenized using a list of separators.

Comment: @AndersonGreen I think this is more complex then I can answer in a comment; I would post a new question.

Comment: @JesseRusak did you get how to get the delimiters along with split strings?

Comment: I would suggest changing `"1,2 3".split(/,| /)`  to `"1,2 3".split(/[, ]/)` to avoid a single character alternation in regex. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47883739/2594907

Comment: for more details on why you need the non-capturing `(?:)` operator: the `.split()` return the match AND the captured groups. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/@@split#return_value

Answer (score 107):

Another simple but effective method is to use split + join repeatedly.

```
"a=b,c:d".split('=').join(',').split(':').join(',').split(',')
```

Essentially doing a split followed by a join is like a global replace so this replaces each separator with a comma then once all are replaced it does a final split on comma

The result of the above expression is:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Expanding on this you could also place it in a function:

```
function splitMulti(str, tokens){
        var tempChar = tokens[0]; // We can use the first token as a temporary join character
        for(var i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++){
            str = str.split(tokens[i]).join(tempChar);
        }
        str = str.split(tempChar);
        return str;
}
```

Usage:

```
splitMulti('a=b,c:d', ['=', ',', ':']) // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

If you use this functionality a lot it might even be worth considering wrapping    `String.prototype.split` for convenience (I think my function is fairly safe - the only consideration is the additional overhead of the conditionals (minor) and the fact that it lacks an implementation of the limit argument if an array is passed).

Be sure to include the `splitMulti` function if using this approach to the below simply  wraps it :). Also worth noting that some people frown on extending built-ins (as many people do it wrong and conflicts can occur) so if in doubt speak to someone more senior before using this or ask on SO :)

```
    var splitOrig = String.prototype.split; // Maintain a reference to inbuilt fn
    String.prototype.split = function (){
        if(arguments[0].length > 0){
            if(Object.prototype.toString.call(arguments[0]) == "[object Array]" ) { // Check if our separator is an array
                return splitMulti(this, arguments[0]);  // Call splitMulti
            }
        }
        return splitOrig.apply(this, arguments); // Call original split maintaining context
    };
```

Usage:

```
var a = "a=b,c:d";
    a.split(['=', ',', ':']); // ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

// Test to check that the built-in split still works (although our wrapper wouldn't work if it didn't as it depends on it :P)
        a.split('='); // ["a", "b,c:d"]
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Why do you write `for(var i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)` and not `for(var i = 1; i < tokens.length; i++)`?

Comment: I had missed that optimization, you're right we can start at `tokens[1]` to save one iteration as `tokens[0] == tempchar` and we split on `tempchar` after iterating over `tokens` to finish up.  I'll update the answer accordingly thanks @tic :).

Comment: It's not wise to play with prototypes. The overhead considerations are very difficult to be aware of because of optimizations that happen deep underneath. You may trigger a flag in C that says 'if they have modified the prototype, assumption X is no longer safe, fallback to this [much slower] code path' for a wide variety of functions. What looked like 'low overhead' can end up slowing down execution of otherwise optimized code by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Not good, because if there was already a `,` in the string, you gonna split by it, even if you didn't want it.

Comment: @BrodaNoel you're correct that's the one major caveat of the first code example. In that particular case it's best to use a character that is safe to split on, in my example the intent was to replace the `,` so it was "safe" but it certainly is something to be mindful of.

The `splitMulti` example addresses this by using the first token in the array as a temporary placeholder as we know we want all of those replaced so it's always safe to use :)

Answer (score 32):

**Lets keep it simple:** (add a "[ ]+" to your RegEx means "1 or more")

This means "+" and "{1,}" are the same.

```
var words = text.split(/[ .:;?!~,`"&|()<>{}\[\]\r\n/\\]+/); // note ' and - are kept
```

Comment: add a "+" at the end means 1 or more

Comment: I would say this is minimal, not simple

Comment: For the + and the - :-D, but also \s instead of the blank char:    var words = text.split(/[\s.:;?!~,`"&|()<>{}\=\+\-\[\]\r\n/\\]+/);

Answer (score 15):

Tricky method:

```
var s = "dasdnk asd, (naks) :d skldma";
var a = s.replace('(',' ').replace(')',' ').replace(',',' ').split(' ');
console.log(a);//["dasdnk", "asd", "naks", ":d", "skldma"]
```

Comment: this is wrong because .replace() does not replaces all elements `:/`

Comment: you can change `'('` for `/(/g` to replace all `(` elements - `g` is the *global* flag for RegExp - so it search for all occurrences of `(` not first one

Answer (score 12):

Here are some cases that may help by using Regex:

- `\W` to match any character else word character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Example:

```js
("Hello World,I-am code").split(/\W+/); // would return [ 'Hello', 'World', 'I', 'am', 'code' ]
```

- `\s+` to match One or more spaces
- `\d` to match a digit
- if you want to split by some characters only let us say `,` and `-` you can use `str.split(/[,-]+/)`...etc

Answer (score 12):

I'm suprised no one has suggested it yet, but my hack-ey (and crazy fast) solution was to just append several 'replace' calls before splitting by the same character.

i.e. to remove a, b, c, d, and e:

```
let str = 'afgbfgcfgdfgefg'
let array = str.replace('a','d').replace('b','d').replace('c','d').replace('e','d').split('d')
```

this can be conveniently generalized for an array of splitters as follows:

```
function splitByMany( manyArgs, string ) {
  do {
    let arg = manyArgs.pop()
    string = string.replace(arg, manyArgs[0])
  } while (manyArgs.length > 2)
  return string.split(manyArgs[0])
}
```

So, in your case, you could then call

```
let array = splitByMany([" ", ","], 'My long string containing commas, and spaces, and more commas');
```

Comment: that's not crazy fast

Answer (score 9):

For those of you who want more customization in their splitting function, I wrote a recursive algorithm that splits a given string with a list of characters to split on. I wrote this before I saw the above post. I hope it helps some frustrated programmers.

```
splitString = function(string, splitters) {
    var list = [string];
    for(var i=0, len=splitters.length; i<len; i++) {
        traverseList(list, splitters[i], 0);
    }
    return flatten(list);
}

traverseList = function(list, splitter, index) {
    if(list[index]) {
        if((list.constructor !== String) && (list[index].constructor === String))
            (list[index] != list[index].split(splitter)) ? list[index] = list[index].split(splitter) : null;
        (list[index].constructor === Array) ? traverseList(list[index], splitter, 0) : null;
        (list.constructor === Array) ? traverseList(list, splitter, index+1) : null;    
    }
}

flatten = function(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc.concat(val.constructor === Array ? flatten(val) : val);
    },[]);
}

var stringToSplit = "people and_other/things";
var splitList = [" ", "_", "/"];
splitString(stringToSplit, splitList);
```

Example above returns: `["people", "and", "other", "things"]`

Note: `flatten` function was taken from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list)

Answer (score 8):

You could just lump all the characters you want to use as separators either singularly or collectively into a regular expression and pass them to the split function. For instance you could write:

```
console.log( "dasdnk asd, (naks) :d skldma".split(/[ \(,\)]+/) );
```

And the output will be:

```
["dasdnk", "asd", "naks", ":d", "skldma"]
```

Answer (score 7):

My refactor of @Brian answer

```js
var string = 'and this is some kind of information and another text and simple and some egample or red or text';
var separators = ['and', 'or'];

function splitMulti(str, separators){
            var tempChar = 't3mp'; //prevent short text separator in split down
            
            //split by regex e.g. \b(or|and)\b
            var re = new RegExp('\\b(' + separators.join('|') + ')\\b' , "g");
            str = str.replace(re, tempChar).split(tempChar);
            
            // trim & remove empty
            return str.map(el => el.trim()).filter(el => el.length > 0);
}

console.log(splitMulti(string, separators))
```

Answer (score 6):

Hi for example if you have split and replace in String 07:05:45PM

```
var hour = time.replace("PM", "").split(":");
```

Result

```
[ '07', '05', '45' ]
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a new way to achieving same in **ES6**:

```js
function SplitByString(source, splitBy) {
  var splitter = splitBy.split('');
  splitter.push([source]); //Push initial value

  return splitter.reduceRight(function(accumulator, curValue) {
    var k = [];
    accumulator.forEach(v => k = [...k, ...v.split(curValue)]);
    return k;
  });
}

var source = "abc,def#hijk*lmn,opq#rst*uvw,xyz";
var splitBy = ",*#";
console.log(SplitByString(source, splitBy));
```

Please note in this function:

- No Regex involved
- **Returns splitted value in same order as it appears in `source`**

Result of above code would be:

[image]

Comment: What if what I want to split is by "hello" and "ciao"?

Comment: @BrodaNoel modify `splitBy.split('')` to your needs. I don't know why `SplitByString()` isn't designed to accept an array as parameter right away, so nobody has to guess where to split anything.

Answer (score 6):

I will provide a classic implementation for a such function. The code works in almost all versions of JavaScript and is somehow optimum.

- It doesn't uses regex, which is hard to maintain
- It doesn't uses new features of JavaScript
- It doesn't uses multiple .split() .join() invocation which require more computer memory

Just pure code:

```js
var text = "Create a function, that will return an array (of string), with the words inside the text";

println(getWords(text));

function getWords(text)
{
    let startWord = -1;
    let ar = [];
    
    for(let i = 0; i <= text.length; i++)
    {
        let c = i < text.length ? text[i] : " ";

        if (!isSeparator(c) && startWord < 0)
        {
            startWord = i;
        }
        
        if (isSeparator(c) && startWord >= 0)
        {
            let word = text.substring(startWord, i);
            ar.push(word);
            
            startWord = -1;
        }
    }

    return ar;
}

function isSeparator(c)
{
    var separators = [" ", "\t", "\n", "\r", ",", ";", ".", "!", "?", "(", ")"];
    return separators.includes(c);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Splitting URL by **.com/** or **.net/**

```
url.split(/\.com\/|\.net\//)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
a = "a=b,c:d"

array = ['=',',',':'];

for(i=0; i< array.length; i++){ a= a.split(array[i]).join(); }
```

this will return the string without a special charecter.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this with reduce and filter. It might not be the most readable solution, or the fastest, and in real life I would probably use [Aarons answere here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/650037/1788771), but it was fun to write.

```js
[' ','_','-','.',',',':','@'].reduce(
(segs, sep) => segs.reduce(
(out, seg) => out.concat(seg.split(sep)), []), 
['E-mail Address: user@domain.com, Phone Number: +1-800-555-0011']
).filter(x => x)
```

Or as a function:

```js
function msplit(str, seps) {
  return seps.reduce((segs, sep) => segs.reduce(
    (out, seg) => out.concat(seg.split(sep)), []
  ), [str]).filter(x => x);
}
```

This will output:

```json
['E','mail','Address','user','domain','com','0','Phone','Number','+1','800','555','0011']
```

Without the filter at the end you would get empty strings in the array where two different separators are next to each other.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this question wile looking for a replacement for the C# string.Split() function which splits a string using the characters in its argument.

In JavaScript you can do the same using map an reduce to iterate over the splitting characters and the intermediate values:

```
let splitters = [",", ":", ";"]; // or ",:;".split("");
let start= "a,b;c:d";
let values = splitters.reduce((old, c) => old.map(v => v.split(c)).flat(), [start]);
// values is ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

flat() is used to flatten the intermediate results so each iteration works on a list of strings without nested arrays. Each iteration applies split to all of the values in old and then returns the list of intermediate results to be split by the next value in splitters. reduce() is initialized with an array containing the initial string value.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the performance of RegEx, but here is another alternative for RegEx leverages native HashSet and works in O( max(str.length, delimeter.length) ) complexity instead:

```
var multiSplit = function(str,delimiter){
    if (!(delimiter instanceof Array))
        return str.split(delimiter);
    if (!delimiter || delimiter.length == 0)
        return [str];
    var hashSet = new Set(delimiter);
    if (hashSet.has(""))
        return str.split("");
    var lastIndex = 0;
    var result = [];
    for(var i = 0;i<str.length;i++){
        if (hashSet.has(str[i])){
            result.push(str.substring(lastIndex,i));
            lastIndex = i+1;
        }
    }
    result.push(str.substring(lastIndex));
    return result;
}

multiSplit('1,2,3.4.5.6 7 8 9',[',','.',' ']);
// Output: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

multiSplit('1,2,3.4.5.6 7 8 9',' ');
// Output: ["1,2,3.4.5.6", "7", "8", "9"]
```

Comment: Yeah, how about you actually test something that you write?http://jsperf.com/slice-vs-custom

This shows that your code is actually 10 times slower in this example. What gave you idea that using 2 times slice, 2 times concat, 1 time split, 1 time shift and no length caching is performance friendly?

Comment: I updated the code, now there is only minimum amount of slice with no shift, split or etc.

Answer (score 2):

I find that one of the main reasons I need this is to split file paths on both `/` and `\`. It's a bit of a tricky regex so I'll post it here for reference:

```
var splitFilePath = filePath.split(/[\/\\]/);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it's easier if you specify what you wanna leave, instead of what you wanna remove.

As if you wanna have only English words, you can use something like this:

```
text.match(/[a-z'\-]+/gi);
```

Examples (run snippet):

```js
var R=[/[a-z'\-]+/gi,/[a-z'\-\s]+/gi];
var s=document.getElementById('s');
for(var i=0;i<R.length;i++)
 {
  var o=document.createElement('option');
  o.innerText=R[i]+'';
  o.value=i;
  s.appendChild(o);
 }
var t=document.getElementById('t');
var r=document.getElementById('r');

s.onchange=function()
 {
  r.innerHTML='';
  var x=s.value;
  if((x>=0)&&(x<R.length))
   x=t.value.match(R[x]);
  for(i=0;i<x.length;i++)
   {
    var li=document.createElement('li');
    li.innerText=x[i];
    r.appendChild(li);
   }
 }
```

```html
<textarea id="t" style="width:70%;height:12em">even, test; spider-man

But saying o'er what I have said before:
My child is yet a stranger in the world;
She hath not seen the change of fourteen years,
Let two more summers wither in their pride,
Ere we may think her ripe to be a bride.

—Shakespeare, William. The Tragedy of Romeo and Juliet</textarea>

<p><select id="s">
 <option selected>Select a regular expression</option>
 <!-- option value="1">/[a-z'\-]+/gi</option>
 <option value="2">/[a-z'\-\s]+/gi</option -->
</select></p>
 <ol id="r" style="display:block;width:auto;border:1px inner;overflow:scroll;height:8em;max-height:10em;"></ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @stephen-sweriduk solution (that was the more interesting to me!), I have slightly modified it to make more generic and reusable:

```
/**
 * Adapted from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript
*/
var StringUtils = {

  /**
   * Flatten a list of strings
   * http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Flatten_a_list
   */
  flatten : function(arr) {
    var self=this;
    return arr.reduce(function(acc, val) {
        return acc.concat(val.constructor === Array ? self.flatten(val) : val);
    },[]);
  },

  /**
   * Recursively Traverse a list and apply a function to each item
   * @param list array
   * @param expression Expression to use in func
   * @param func function of (item,expression) to apply expression to item
   *
   */
  traverseListFunc : function(list, expression, index, func) {
    var self=this;
    if(list[index]) {
        if((list.constructor !== String) && (list[index].constructor === String))
            (list[index] != func(list[index], expression)) ? list[index] = func(list[index], expression) : null;
        (list[index].constructor === Array) ? self.traverseListFunc(list[index], expression, 0, func) : null;
        (list.constructor === Array) ? self.traverseListFunc(list, expression, index+1, func) : null;
    }
  },

  /**
   * Recursively map function to string
   * @param string
   * @param expression Expression to apply to func
   * @param function of (item, expressions[i])
   */
  mapFuncToString : function(string, expressions, func) {
    var self=this;
    var list = [string];
    for(var i=0, len=expressions.length; i<len; i++) {
        self.traverseListFunc(list, expressions[i], 0, func);
    }
    return self.flatten(list);
  },

  /**
   * Split a string
   * @param splitters Array of characters to apply the split
   */
  splitString : function(string, splitters) {
    return this.mapFuncToString(string, splitters, function(item, expression) {
      return item.split(expression);
    })
  },

}
```

and then

```
var stringToSplit = "people and_other/things";
var splitList = [" ", "_", "/"];
var splittedString=StringUtils.splitString(stringToSplit, splitList);
console.log(splitList, stringToSplit, splittedString);
```

that gives back as the original:

```
[ ' ', '_', '/' ] 'people and_other/things' [ 'people', 'and', 'other', 'things' ]
```

Answer (score 1):

> An easy way to do this is to process each character of the string with each delimiter and build an array of the splits:

```
splix = function ()
{
  u = [].slice.call(arguments); v = u.slice(1); u = u[0]; w = [u]; x = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < u.length; ++i)
  {
    for (j = 0; j < v.length; ++j)
    {
      if (u.slice(i, i + v[j].length) == v[j])
      {
        y = w[x].split(v[j]); w[x] = y[0]; w[++x] = y[1];
      };
    };
  };
  
  return w;
};
```

```js
console.logg = function ()
{
  document.body.innerHTML += "<br>" + [].slice.call(arguments).join();
}

splix = function() {
  u = [].slice.call(arguments);
  v = u.slice(1);
  u = u[0];
  w = [u];
  x = 0;
  console.logg("Processing: <code>" + JSON.stringify(w) + "</code>");

  for (i = 0; i < u.length; ++i) {
    for (j = 0; j < v.length; ++j) {
      console.logg("Processing: <code>[\x22" + u.slice(i, i + v[j].length) + "\x22, \x22" + v[j] + "\x22]</code>");
      if (u.slice(i, i + v[j].length) == v[j]) {
        y = w[x].split(v[j]);
        w[x] = y[0];
        w[++x] = y[1];
        console.logg("Currently processed: " + JSON.stringify(w) + "\n");
      };
    };
  };

  console.logg("Return: <code>" + JSON.stringify(w) + "</code>");
};

setTimeout(function() {
  console.clear();
  splix("1.23--4", ".", "--");
}, 250);
```

```css
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto");

body {font: 20px Roboto;}
```

> Usage: `splix(string, delimiters...)`
>
> Example: `splix("1.23--4", ".", "--")`
>
> Returns: `["1", "23", "4"]`

Answer (score 1):

Not the best way but works to Split with Multiple and Different seperators/delimiters

html

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Split with Multiple and Different seperators/delimiters</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

javascript

```
<script>
function myFunction() {

 var str = "How : are | you doing : today?";
 var res = str.split(' | ');

 var str2 = '';
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < res.length; i++) { 
    str2 += res[i];
    
    if (i != res.length-1) {
      str2 += ",";
    }
 }
 var res2 = str2.split(' : ');

 //you can add countless options (with or without space)

 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res2;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out my simple library on [Github](https://github.com/gbenroscience/gscanner-js)

If you really do not want to visit or interact with the repo, here is the working code:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param {type} input The string input to be split
 * @param {type} includeTokensInOutput If true, the tokens are retained in the splitted output.
 * @param {type} tokens The tokens to be employed in splitting the original string.
 * @returns {Scanner}
 */
function Scanner(input, includeTokensInOutput, tokens) {
    this.input = input;
    this.includeTokensInOutput = includeTokensInOutput;
    this.tokens = tokens;
}

Scanner.prototype.scan = function () {
    var inp = this.input;

    var parse = [];
    this.tokens.sort(function (a, b) {
        return b.length - a.length; //ASC, For Descending order use: b - a
    });
    for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++) {


        for (var j = 0; j < this.tokens.length; j++) {

            var token = this.tokens[j];
            var len = token.length;
            if (len > 0 && i + len <= inp.length) {
                var portion = inp.substring(i, i + len);
                if (portion === token) {
                    if (i !== 0) {//avoid empty spaces
                        parse[parse.length] = inp.substring(0, i);
                    }
                    if (this.includeTokensInOutput) {
                        parse[parse.length] = token;
                    }
                    inp = inp.substring(i + len);
                    i = -1;
                    break;
                }

            }

        }

    }
    if (inp.length > 0) {
          parse[parse.length] = inp;
    }

    return parse;


};
```

The usage is very straightforward:

```
    var tokens = new Scanner("ABC+DE-GHIJK+LMNOP", false , new Array('+','-')).scan();

console.log(tokens);
```

Gives:

```
['ABC', 'DE', 'GHIJK', 'LMNOP']
```

And if you wish to include the splitting tokens `(+ and -)` in the output, set the `false` to `true` and voila! it still works.

The usage would now be:

```
var tokens = new Scanner("ABC+DE-GHIJK+LMNOP", true , new Array('+','-')).scan();
```

and

```
console.log(tokens);
```

would give:

```
['ABC', '+', 'DE', '-', 'GHIJK', '+', 'LMNOP']
```

**ENJOY!**

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively elegant way of splitting a string I found.
Not sure the world needs an nth solution, but I felt it ws worth sharing.

```js
/**
 * Split an input string with an array of single characters
 * @param {string} inputStr the input string
 * @param {string[]} splitterArray an array of single characters
 * @param {boolean} shouldTrim true if each chunk should be trimmed
 * @returns the splitted string
 */
export const multiSplit = (inputStr, splitterArray, shouldTrim = true) => {
  // Let's make sure to have only single characters as splitters and make it a string
  const splitters = splitterArray.map((d) => d[0]).join('')
  // The regex that will be used to split the input string, with or without trimming
  // The regex makes sure no empty strings are delivered
  const regexStr = shouldTrim ? `(?:\\s*[${splitters}]\\s*)+` : `[${splitters}]+`
  // We use the String.split(RegExp) function to get an array of split strings
  return `${inputStr}`.split(RegExp(regexStr))
}
```

Tests results:

```js
> s='amoghrumfkgh,vclrgehuzpgoma,izehrcgmhvzclericghu,movehruq ezr gzerg hzeg nrcf xfgr, faz, ezrt,rgze rg aeoirhg    , ,    , zaiufharefg'

> multiSplit(s,[","],true)
[
  'amoghrumfkgh',
  'vclrgehuzpgoma',
  'izehrcgmhvzclericghu',
  'movehruq ezr gzerg hzeg nrcf xfgr',
  'faz',
  'ezrt',
  'rgze rg aeoirhg',
  'zaiufharefg'
]

> multiSplit(s,[","],false)
[
  'amoghrumfkgh',
  'vclrgehuzpgoma',
  'izehrcgmhvzclericghu',
  'movehruq ezr gzerg hzeg nrcf xfgr',
  ' faz',
  ' ezrt',
  'rgze rg aeoirhg    ',
  ' ',
  '    ',
  ' zaiufharefg'
]
```

Answer (score -2):

I use regexp:

```
str =  'Write a program that extracts from a given text all palindromes, e.g. "ABBA", "lamal", "exe".';

var strNew = str.match(/\w+/g);

// Output: ["Write", "a", "program", "that", "extracts", "from", "a", "given", "text", "all", "palindromes", "e", "g", "ABBA", "lamal", "exe"]
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything with *palindromes*, just words.