# How split a string in jquery with multiple strings as separator

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, split

i want to split a string in jquery or javascript with multiple separator.
for one string as separator we can have :

```
var x = "Name: John Doe\nAge: 30\nBirth Date: 12/12/1981";
var pieces = x.split("\n"), part;
for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
         bla bla bla
}
```

But i want to split such that string(x) with : `Age:` and `Date:` (mean a string array as separator)
and at last i want a sting array with these parts : "Name: John Doe\n"," 30\nBirth "," 12/12/1981"
that x string is just an example and i dont have any string like that!
how can i rewrite theses codes?

Comment: Repeat....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do

```
var tokens = x.split(/Age:|Date:/g);
```

This gives 3 strings :

```
["Name: John Doe
", " 30
Birth ", " 12/12/1981"]
```

If you want also to get the separators, use

```
var tokens = x.split(/(Age:|Date:)/g);
```

This gives 5 strings :

```
["Name: John Doe
", "Age:", " 30
Birth ", "Date:", " 12/12/1981"]
```

If you want to build your regexp dynamically use

```
var separators = ["Date:", "Age:"];
var tokens = x.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

or

```
var separators = ["Date:", "Age:"];
var tokens = x.split(new RegExp('('+separators.join('|')+')', 'g'));
```

Comment: Make `\n?` a part of regex.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function based on one of @DenysSéguret's answers:

```
String.prototype.xSplit = function(separators){
    return this
      .split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'))
      .map(function(bar){ return bar.trim() }); // remove trailing spaces
}
```

Usage:

```
var foo = "Before date Date: between date & age Age: after age";
foo = foo.xSplit(​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​["Date:", "Age:"]);
```

Outcome:

```
foo == ["Before date", "between date & age", "after age"]
```