# Split a string based on multiple delimiters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, split

I was trying to split a string based on multiple delimiters by referring [How split a string in jquery with multiple strings as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867182/how-split-a-string-in-jquery-with-multiple-strings-as-separator)

Since multiple delimiters I decided to follow

```
var separators = [' ', '+', '-', '(', ')', '*', '/', ':', '?'];
var tokens = x.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

But I'm getting error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: / |+|-|(|)|*|/|:|?/: Nothing to repeat
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Comment: Can anyone help me with this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313874/add-space-in-the-string-before-and-after-certain-characters

Answer (score 64, accepted):

escape needed for regex related characters +,-,(,),*,?

```
var x = "adfds+fsdf-sdf";

var separators = [' ', '\\\+', '-', '\\\(', '\\\)', '\\*', '/', ':', '\\\?'];
console.log(separators.join('|'));
var tokens = x.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g'));
console.log(tokens);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cpdjZ/

Comment: This works great! 
what exactly is `new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g')` doing here though?

Comment: @HussienK enables alternation in the expression, look here http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html

Comment: Man. The RegEx. This is why I've taken so long to actually learn them. Why the heck does the + have three slashes in front, but the * have 2 slashes, and the :, / and space have none?

Answer (score 12):

This should work:

```
var separators = [' ', '+', '(', ')', '*', '\\/', ':', '?', '-'];
var tokens = x.split(new RegExp('[' + separators.join('') + ']', 'g'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Generated regex will be using **regex character class: `/[ +()*\/:?-]/g`**

This way you don't need to escape anything.

Comment: Can you provide an example of var x?

Comment: var arr = str.split(new RegExp('[|!=&+- ]', 'g'));- error

Answer (score 9):

The following would be an easier way of accomplishing the same thing.

```
var tokens = x.split(new RegExp('[-+()*/:? ]', 'g'));​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note that `-` must come first (or be escaped), otherwise it will think it is the `range` operator (e.g. `a-z`)

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to escape the +, * and ?, since they've got special meaning in most regex languages

Answer (score 1):

This is because characters like `+` and `*` have special meaning in Regex.

Change your join from `|` to `|\` and you should be fine, escaping the literals.

Comment: I'm getting error when I changed it to |\  'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;' I think it is because when |\ is entered inside quote the quote is getting escaped. How to avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split based in multiple regexes and dont want to write a big regex
You could use `replace` and `split`.
Like this:

```js
const spliters = [
 /(\[products\])/g,
 /(\[link\])/g,
 /(\[llinks\])/g,
];
let newString = "aa [products] bb [link] [products] cc [llinks] dd";
spliters.forEach(regex => {
 newString = newString.replace(regex, match => `æææ${match}æææ`);
});
const mySplit = newString.split(/æææ([^æ]+)æææ/)
console.log(mySplit);
```

This works very well for my case.