# Add space in the string before and after certain characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, space

I want to add space in the string before and after certain characters.

```
var x = "asdasdasdasd+adasdasdasd/asdasdasdasd*asdasdasd-asdasdasd:asdasdasdadasdasd?";
```

I want to add space before and after

```
var separators = ['+', '-', '(', ')', '*', '/', ':', '?'];
```

So the output will be like

```
asdasdasdasd + adasdasdasd / asdasdasdasd * asdasdasd - as ( dasd ) asd : asdasdasdadasdasd ?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Regex for that.

```
for (var i = 0; i < separators.length; i++) { 
      var rg = new RegExp("\\" + separators[i], "g"); 
      x = x.replace(rg, " " + separators[i] + " "); 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You may use something like that:

```
var str = x.replace(new RegExp('\\' + separators.join('|\\'), 'g'), ' $& ')
```

Comment: I'm getting error' Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[+-()*/:?]/: Range out of order in character class '

Comment: @SreekeshOkky Yeah, that was `join` problem. Please see the updated version. It should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

you ca try this | [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/H6gzf/)

```
function fix(val)
{
  var separators = ['+', '-', '(', ')', '*', '/', ':', '?'];
  var result="";
  flag=true;
  for(var i=0;i<val.length;i++)
  {
     flag=true;
     for(var j=0;j<separators.length;j++)
     {
        if(val[i]==separators[j])
        {
            result += " " + val[i] + " ";
            flag=false;         
        }
     }
     if(flag)
     {
            result +=val[i];
     }
}

alert(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this looks fairly easy...

```
var separators = ['+', '-', '(', ')', '*', '/', ':', '?'];
var x = "asdasdasdasd+adasdasdasd/asdasdasdasd*asdasdasd-asdasdasd:asdasdasdadasdasd?";
$(separators).each(function (index, element) {
    x = x.replace(element, " " + element + " ");
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gPza4/

For the people who want to understand this code, what I basically do is to make the separators array to a jQuery object and then iterate over it while replacing the occurances of those separators in the string x with their "spaced" form.