# Separate value from string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string in which every value is between `[]` and it has a `.` at the end. How can I separate all values from the string?

This is the example string:

```
[value01][value02 ][value03 ]. [value04 ]

//want something like this 
v1 = value01;
v2 = value02;
v3 = value03;
v4 = value04
```

The number of values is not constant. How can I get all values separately from this string?

Comment: Try [RegEx](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: I don't see any questions here.

Comment: please specify your requirement..

Comment: is this a question? do you just want the numbers within [], what is with the dot?

Comment: i want text that is between `[]`

Comment: Please I beg you provide Sample INPUT and OUTPUT,

Comment: how would it handle situations like [value01][value02][valu[e]03]

Answer (score 2):

Use regular expressions to specify multiple separators. Please check the following posts:

[How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/)

[Split a string based on multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313541)

```
var str = "[value01][value02 ][value03 ]. [value04 ]"
var arr = str.split(/[\[\]\.\s]+/);
arr.shift(); arr.pop(); //discard the first and last "" elements
console.log( arr ); //output: ["value01", "value02", "value03", "value04"]
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/mN8zw/)

**How This Works**

`.split(/[\[\]\.\s]+/)` splits the string at points where it finds one or more of the following characters: `[] .`. Now, since these characters are also found at the beginning and end of the string, `.shift()` discards the first element, and `.pop()` discards the last element, both of which are empty strings. However, your may want to use `.filter()` and your can replace lines 2 and 3 with:

```
var arr = str.split(/[\[\]\.\s]+/).filter(function(elem) { return elem.length > 0; });
```

Now you can use jQuery/JS to iterate through the values:

```
$.each( arr, function(i,v) {
    console.log( v ); // outputs the i'th value;
});
```

And `arr.length` will give you the number of elements you have.

Comment: Sure, will do shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the characters between "[" and "]" and the data is regular and always has the pattern:

```
'[chars][chars]...[chars]'
```

then you can get the chars using [*match*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10) to get sequences of characters that aren't "[" or "]":

```
var values = '[value01][value02 ][value03 ][value04 ]'.match(/[^\[\]]+/g)
```

which returns an array, so *values* is:

```
["value01", "value02 ", "value03 ", "value04 "]
```

Match is very widely supported, so no cross browser issues.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xVLQ/

Regex patern: /(\w)+/ig
Matches all words using \w (alphanumeric combos). Whitespace, brackets, dots, square brackets are all non-matching, so they don't get returned.

What I do is create a object to hold results in key/value pairs such as v1:'value01'. You can iterate through this object, or you can access the values directly using objRes.v1

```
var str = '[value01][value02 ][value03 ]. [value04 ]';
var myRe = /(\w)+/ig;
var res;
var objRes = {};
var i=1;
while ( ( res = myRe.exec(str) ) != null )
{
    objRes['v'+i] = res[0];
    i++;    
}
console.log(objRes);
```