# Split string with multiple separators

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string where I need to separate it by +-*/ and put it into array.

I've tried this code that I also found here, but it doesn't seem to be working. It gives me the error "Invalid regular expression: /+|-|*|//: Nothing to repeat."

```
var separators = ['+', '-', '*', '/'];
var numbers = x.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'), ''));
```

Any advice on how should I do this?

Comment: Does the string contain special characters?

Comment: the problem is that some of those characters have special meanings in a RegExp ... so you need to escape them with more \\ than you think

Comment: `+` and `*` have special significance in regex. Try `string.split(/[\+-\*\/]/g)`

Comment: @Harsha No. There's no special characters other than the four

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split a string based on multiple delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313541/split-a-string-based-on-multiple-delimiters)

Answer (score 14):

Try this.

```js
var str = "i-have_six*apples+doyou/know.doe";
console.log(str.split(/[.\*+-/_]/));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is your answer,

```js
x = "This+is*test/the*theunder-Yes";
var separators = ['\\\+', '-', '\\*', '/'];

var numbers = x.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|'),'g'));
console.log(numbers);
```

It is because, your +,* are regex related wild card characters. You can't use as is.

Comment: Where is the related question?

Answer (score 2):

use regex split

```
    var tempvar = (X).split(/[+-/*]+/);
```

This should return as array split.
eg : X = 1+2-3/4

```
alert(x) would return as 

    1,2,3,4
```