# How can I split a string based on three delimiters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, split, vue-component

My code like this :

```
<template>
    ...
        <p v-for="club in clubs">{{club}}</p>
    ...
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    clubs: ''
  }),
  mounted () {
    let dataClub =  "- City\\t - MU\\t - Liverpool\\t - Arsenal\\t - Chelsea"
    // let dataClub =  "- City\n - MU\n - Liverpool\n - Arsenal\n - Chelsea"
    // let dataClub =  "City;MU;Liverpool;Arsenal;Chelsea"
    let dc = dataClub.split(/[\n;]/)
    this.clubs = dc
  }
}
</script>
```

dataClub is dynamic. It can be separated with `;` and can also be separated with `\n`. Other than that it can also be separated by the sign `\\t`

How can I do a split if there are 3 separators?

I try `let dc = dataClub.split(/[\n;\\t]/)`, but it does not works

Comment: What is the source of this data?  Note that `\\t`, with _two_ backslashes, is not a tab, it's a tab with a backslash.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I get it from a response of API

Comment: Does the response have literal backslashes followed by `t`s, or does the response have literal tab characters?

Comment: @CertainPerformance The example like this : https://postimg.cc/vckr4hvC

Comment: So is that a literal backslash and a `t`, or a tab character?

Comment: @CertainPerformance I do not know. I have to ask the company that provided the API. Maybe you can provide answers with several options

Comment: All you have to do to check to see if the string includes it is `dataClub.includes('\t')` vs `dataClub.includes('\\t')` - if you have control over the Javascript, you can use the Javascript to see what the string contains. I posted an answer but I deleted it because I'm still pretty unsure what your situation actually is

Comment: @CertainPerformance Okay thanks. I will ask it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on multiple strings/characters using `|` (the `or` operator) in the regular expression. The snippet has some examples, including `\\t` or `\t` (the last being a `tab` character).

```js
const splitData = str => str.split(/\\t|\n|;|\t/);

const dataClub1 =  "- City\\t- MU\\t- Liverpool\\t- Arsenal\\t- Chelsea"; // \\t
const dataClub2 =  `- City
- MU
- Liverpool
- Arsenal
- Chelsea`; // \n
const dataClub3 =  "- City;- MU;- Liverpool;- Arsenal;- Chelsea"; // ;
const dataClub4 =  `- City\t- MU\t- Liverpool\t- Arsenal\t- Chelsea`; // \t

console.log(splitData(dataClub1));
console.log(splitData(dataClub2));
console.log(splitData(dataClub3));
console.log(splitData(dataClub4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

referring to this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313633/4298881

```
let separators = ['\\\\t', ';', '\\n'];
let regex = new RegExp(separators.join('|'), 'g');
dataClub.split(regex); // ["- City", " - MU", " - Liverpool", " - Arsenal", " - Chelsea"]
```

Answer (score 0):

While putting separators in an array(dataClub.split(/['\t','\n',';']/) will also split the city, since regex is either of them. Making regex to exactly match the separators will help.

```js
let dataClub =  "- City\\t - MU\\t - Liverpool\\t - Arsenal\\t - Chelsea";
const splittedDc = dataClub.split(/\\t|\n|;/);
console.log(splittedDc);
```