# Split by Multiple Strings or a Colon (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, regex

I know that to split by strings I can use e.g. `x.split(/Age:|Date:/g);`
[How split a string in jquery with multiple strings as separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867182/how-split-a-string-in-jquery-with-multiple-strings-as-separator) and to split by a character, like `:` I can use `x.split(':');`

I need to split a string by the following, if applicable

```
:
am
AM
pm
PM
```

Tried both of these but they don't work.

```
var array = str.split('/:|am|AM|pm|PM/g');
var array = str.split('/\:|am|AM|pm|PM/g');
var array = str.split('/(:|am|AM|pm|PM)/g');
```

JSFiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/dkasce2e/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Quotes while using the regex pattern. Use the following instead

`var array = str.split(/:|am|AM|pm|PM/g);`

Here is your full example:

```js
function splitTime(str) {

 var array = str.split(/:|am|AM|pm|PM/g);
        console.log("[0]: " + array[0] + " [1]: " + array[1] + " [2]: " + array[2]);

}

splitTime('12:20am');
splitTime('00:20am');
splitTime('4:00PM');
splitTime('14:30am');
```

RegEx is supported without quotes and typically surrounded by `/` followed by access flags. In Javascript RegEx is supported in `match`, `replace`, `search`, `split` functions of String Object. 
More details can be found in [Javascript Regular Expressions Guide in Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: Indeed, its a common mistake people make when using regex patters, some APIs need the pattern to be in quotes(takes as a String) and some as raw regex pattern,  like the above api. 
More details about using RegEx in javascript can be found in this excellent guide. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Regex doesn't go inside quotation marks in JS. '/myregexpattern/' will look for exactly that string. Use /yourpatternhere/ instead.