# Javascript: Returning the last word in a string

Tags: javascript, string, substring

right to it:

I have a `words` string which has two words in it, and i need to return the last word. They are seperated by a " ". How do i do this?

```
function test(words) {

var n = words.indexOf(" ");
var res = words.substring(n+1,-1);
return res;

}
```

I've been told to use `indexOf` and `substring` but it's not required. Anyone have an easy way to do this? (with or without `indexOf` and `substring`)

Comment: `sentence.split(" ").slice(-1)`

Comment: `lastIndexOf` and `slice`!

Comment: I don't get it. You have already solved your problem in the question. What do you expect us to do?

Comment: @Blender post an answer.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: It's not an interesting question.

Comment: @Blender yes. very simple and common question

Comment: i've solved it? because this doesn't work for me

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try this:

you can use words with n word length.

example:

```
  words = "Hello World";
  words = "One Hello World";
  words = "Two Hello World";
  words = "Three Hello World";
```

All will return same value: "World"

```
function test(words) {
    var n = words.split(" ");
    return n[n.length - 1];

}
```

Comment: Note this will not work for a string with a space at the end `("Hello World ").split(" ");` returns `["Hello", "World", ""]`. Where the "last word" would be `""`.

Comment: Use can do this ```words.trim().split(" ");```

Answer (score 69):

You could also:

```
words.split(" ").pop();
```

Just chaining the result (array) of the split function and popping the last element would do the trick in just one line :)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 39):

```
var data = "Welcome to Stack Overflow";
console.log(data.split(" ").splice(-1));
```

**Output**

```
[ 'Overflow' ]
```

This works even if there is no space in the original string, so you can straight away get the element like this

```
var data = "WelcometoStackOverflow";
console.log(data.split(" ").splice(-1)[0]);
```

**Output**

```
WelcometoStackOverflow
```

Comment: It is possible to replace
    splice(-1)[0]
by
    pop()

Comment: you would have to trim() a trailing space makes this bomb

Comment: Very long time ago.. but..If you would like to remove any extra spaces in between words use instead: `data.split(/\s+/).splice(-1));`

Answer (score 12):

You want the *last word*, which suggests [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/lastIndexOf) may be more efficient for you than `indexOf`. Further, [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) is also a method available to *Strings*.

```
var str = 'foo bar fizz buzz';
str.slice(
    str.lastIndexOf(' ') + 1
); // "buzz"
```

See [**this jsperf**](http://jsperf.com/split-vs-slice-indexof/4) from 2011 showing the ***split** vs **indexOf + slice** vs **indexOf + substring*** and [**this perf**](http://jsperf.com/indexof-vs-lastindexof/3) which shows `lastIndexOf` is about the same efficiency as `indexOf`, it mostly depends on how long until the match happens.

Comment: short, clean, no mess no fuss.

Answer (score 4):

To complete Jyoti Prakash, you could add multiple separators (`\s`|`,`) to split your string (via [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript))

Example:

```
function lastWord(words) {
  var n = words.split(/[\s,]+/) ;
  return n[n.length - 1];
}
```

Note: regex `\s` means [whitespace characters](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_whitespace.asp) : A space character, A tab character, A carriage return character, A new line character, A vertical tab character, A form feed character

### snippet

```js
var wordsA = "Hello  Worlda"; // tab
var wordsB = "One Hello\nWorldb";
var wordsC = "Two,Hello,Worldc";
var wordsD = "Three Hello Worldd";

function lastWord(words) {
  var n = words.split(/[\s,]+/);
  return n[n.length - 1];
}


$('#A').html( lastWord(wordsA) );
$('#B').html( lastWord(wordsB) );
$('#C').html( lastWord(wordsC) );
$('#D').html( lastWord(wordsD) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
A:<span id="A"></span><br/>
B:<span id="B"></span><br/>
C:<span id="C"></span><br/>
D:<span id="D"></span><br/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding from the accepted answer, if the input string is `"Hello World "` (note the extra space at the end), it will return `''`. The code below should anticipate in case user fat-fingered `" "`:

```
var lastWord= function(str) {
  if (str.trim() === ""){
    return 0;
  } else {   
    var splitStr = str.split(' ');
    splitStr = splitStr.filter(lengthFilter);
    return splitStr[splitStr.length - 1];
  }
};

var lengthFilter = function(str){
    return str.length >= 1;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to use slice method:-

For example:-

```
let words = "hello world";
let res = words.slice(6,13);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I'd use words.split as you don't need to know the position of the space.  You're giving yourself more work.

Answer (score 1):

According to me the easiest way is:

```
lastName.trim().split(" ").slice(-1)
```

It will give the last word in a phrase, even if there are trailing spaces.
I used it to show the last name initials. I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Get last word from a text
 * @param {!string} text
 * @return {!string}
 */
function getLastWord(text) {
  return text
    .split(new RegExp("[" + RegExp.quote(wordDelimiters + sentenceDelimiters) + "]+"))
    .filter(x => !!x)
    .slice(-1)
    .join(" ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use .slice and .lastIndexOf in JavaScript. Its pretty simple to use.

```js
const a = "Bringing founders's ideas to life";
const b = a.lastIndexOf(" ");
const word = a.slice(b, a.length);
console.log(word);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Use `split()`

```
function lastword(words){
 array = words.split(' ');

 return array[1]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its pretty straight forward.
You have got two words separated by space.
Lets break the string into array using split() method.
Now your array has two elements with indices 0 and 1.
Alert the element with index 1.

```
var str="abc def";
var arr=str.split(" ");
alert(arr[1]);
```