# Splitting a string at special character with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, split, email-validation

I am trying to "intelligently" pre-fill a form, I want to prefill the firstname and lastname inputs based on a user email address, so for example,

> jon.doe@email.com RETURNS Jon Doe
>   jon_doe@email.com RETURN Jon Doe
>   jon-doe@email.com RETURNS Jon Doe

I have managed to get the string before the `@`,

```
var email = letters.substr(0, letters.indexOf('@'));
```

But cant work out how to split() when the separator can be multiple values, I can do this,

```
email.split("_")
```

but how can I split on other email address valid special characters?

Comment: What's a "special character"? Notice that all characters are valid in an email address.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

JavaScript's [string `split` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can take a regex.

For example the following will split on `.`, `-`, and `_`.

```
"i-am_john.doe".split(/[.\-_]/)
```

Returning the following.

```
["i", "am", "john", "doe"]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a regular expression for what you want to split on. You can for example split on anything that isn't a letter:

```
var parts = email.split(/[^A-Za-z]/);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/xt3Lb9e6/

Answer (score 1):

Regular Expressions --

```
email.split(/[_\.-]/)
```

This one matches (therefore splits at) any of (a character set, indicated by []) _, ., or -.

Here's a good resource for learning regular expressions: http://qntm.org/files/re/re.html

Comment: You should offer some more explanation of your answer

Answer (score 1):

You can split a string using a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). To match `.`, `_` or `-`, you can use a character class, for example `[.\-_]`. The syntax for regular expressions in JavaScript is `/expression/`, so your example would look like:

```
email.split(/[\.\-_]/);
```

Note that the backslashes are to prevent `.` and `-` being interpreted as special characters.  `.` is a special character class representing any character. In a character class, `-` can be used to specify ranges, such as `[a-z]`.

If you require a dynamic list of characters to split on, you can build a regular expression using the `RegExp` constructor. For example:

```
var specialChars = ['.', '\\-', '_'];
var specialRegex = new RegExp('[' + specialChars.join('') + ']');
email.split(specialRegex);
```

More information on regular expressions in JavaScript can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to do it, just provide a list of the characters in square brackets and escape if necessary.

email.split("[_-\.]");

Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you want to pass in a regular expression, it cannot be a string literal. ```split("[_-\.]");``` will split on the exact, full sequence ```[_-\.]```.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that you need to use the [split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Split function works by taking an argument to split the string on.  Multiple values can be split via regular expression.  For you usage, try something like

```
var re = /[\._\-]/;
var split = email.split(re, 2);
```

This should result in an array with two values, first/second name.  The second argument is the number of elements returned.

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsFiddle to show how this could be done :

```
function printName(email){
    var name = email.split('@')[0];
    // source : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript
    var returnVal = name.split(/[._-]/g);
    return returnVal;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ts6nx9tt/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you define your seperators, below code can return all alternatives for you.

```
var arr = ["_",".","-"];

var email = letters.substr(0, letters.indexOf('@'));
arr.map(function(val,index,rest){
   var r = email.split(val);
   if(r.length > 1){
     return r.join(' ');
   }
   return "";
}
);
```