# How to split array elements by special characters

Tags: javascript, split

I have an string array like this:

```js
var strings = ['elephant-rides', 'are', 'fun!'];
```

How can I achieve the result like given below?

```js
var result = ['elephant', '-', 'rides', 'are', 'fun', '!'];
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266372/javascript-splitting-a-string-at-special-character

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could match word or not word characters in a flat array.

```js
var strings = ['elephant-rides', 'are', 'fun!'],
    result = strings.flatMap(s => s.match(/\w+|\W+/g));

console.log(result);
```