# How seprate character from variable?

Tags: javascript, next.js

How can I export first character to 1 character after "."

I've got data from API

```
{POWER : 1343.45}
{POWER : 15623.34577}
{POWER : 123.434}
```

I need just `123.4` from `123.45`, `15623.3` from `15623.34577`etc.

What should I do?

Comment: try to use split() see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266372/splitting-a-string-at-special-character-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and match() to solve this

```
const str = `{POWER : 1343.45}
 {POWER : 15623.34577}
 {POWER : 123.434}`
const reg = /\d+\.\d{1}/g
const result = str.match(reg) //["1343.4","15623.3","123.4"]
console.log(result)
```