# Split values in Javascript array based on multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, handlebars.js, lodash

Is there any ways to split an array of string in JavaScript based on multiple values.

```
var inputArray = ["[dim].[att].&[1]","[dim].[att].&[2]","[dim2].[att2].&[2]","[dim].[att].[All].Children","[dim4].[att5].[All].Children", "[m1].[123]", "[m1].[m4]"];

var splitBasedOn = `[".&",".[All].Unknown",".[All]", "."];`
```

so I want to split values in `inputArray`, based on values in `splitBasedOn` array.

I will first split on first value in splitBasedOn array then I will try to split based on second value in splitBasedOn and so on.

Without using multiple for loops how can I acheive desired result.

Comment: What ist he minimum complexity you need, O(n) or O(n^2)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: there is confussion at one point.
When we get the output of first operation then after that do you want to perform operation on that previous output (i.e Chaining of operation) ?
Or you want to keep your base string same for all operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `RegExp` constructor and alternation operator `|` and don't forget to make use of global flag `g`.

```
inputArray.forEach(function(str){
   console.log(str.split(new RegExp(splitBasedOn.join("|"), "g"));
});
```

Comment: But be careful to escape special characters like `.`, `[`, etc.