# How to split the String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, split

I have a string `[{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880934},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935}]`

I want output as `[{8.55701,76.880934},..etc]` only numbers.

This is a JSON string -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var myVar = ' <%= request.getAttribute("Map") %>';    /* retrieve json from request attribute */
 var result = myVar.split(',',2);
 var latitude = parseFloat(result[0].replace('"Latitude":',''));
 var longitude = parseFloat(result[1].split(':'));
 alert(latitude);  
 </script>
```

I have tried but not getting it.

Comment: Did you even try? Have you check the `split()` method? `JSON.parse` etc..? What have you tried? SO is not a free mechanical turd.

Comment: Why not use `eval()` or `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: You have to know that, objects are key-value pairs, you can't just store them by themselves. so you'd have to then use an array instead. `[[8.55701,76.880934],..etc] to keep them in pairs if you want them to be.
Alternatively you could just ave one array where every other number is a longitude, and every other other number is a latitude.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Use simple Regular expression to remove the strings:

```
.replace(/\"\w+\":/g, '');

'[{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880934},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935}]'.replace(/\"\w+\":/g, '');
```

And if you want to get the values you can use JSON.parse:

```
var coords = JSON.parse('[{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880934},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935}]');

// And loop
coords.forEach(function(coord) {
  console.log('latitude', coord.Latitude);
  console.log('longitude', coord.Longitude);
});
```

Comment: Vote up or mark as correct if it helps you. You're very welcome

Answer (score 1):

try this, this function will return a string as you expected out put.

```
function pareseJSONStr(str){

    var json = JSON.parse(str);
    var rslt = [];
    json.forEach(function(obj){
        rslt.push("{" + obj.Latitude + ", " + obj.Longitude + "}");
    });
    return "[" + rslt.join(",") + "]"
}
```

call this function as

```
var mystr = '[{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880934},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935}]';
pareseStr(mystr);
```

returns a string

```
"[{8.55701, 76.880934},{8.55701, 76.880935},{8.55701, 76.880935}]"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your strange data format just use it:

```
var convertStrange = function( string ) {
    return '[' + JSON.parse( string ).map( function( item ) {
        return '{' + [ item.Latitude, item.Longitude ].join( ',' ) + '}';
    } ).join( ',' ) + ']';
};
```

So,

```
convertStrange('[{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880934},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935},{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935}]')
```

will return string

```
[{8.55701,76.880934},{8.55701,76.880935},{8.55701,76.880935}]
```

Comment: what if it's an ACTUAL string (looks like a REAL *JSON* string to me) - easy fix - JSON.parse the string first :D ... of course, then the output HAS to be a string ... because it's not valid anything else

Comment: It is a valid array, containing objects, nope?

Comment: I mean the output "required" in the question, your code is good man

Comment: I suppose it's a misprint or some like that, or he really wants invalid data format?

Comment: he wants a string maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
{8.55701,76.880934}
```

is wrong object construction. Objects must be name:value pairs so it can only be

```
{name1:8.55701, name2:76.880934}
```

or you can use an array like

```
[[8.55701, 76.880934], ... ]
```

if you want it as a string use this;

```
var string = '[{"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880934}, {"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935}, {"Latitude":8.55701,"Longitude":76.880935}]';
var newString = string.replace(/\"Latitude\":|\"Longitude\":/g, "");
```