# Split string on newline and comma

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My input String is like

```
abc,def,wer,str
```

Currently its splitting  only on comma but in future it will contain both comma and newline.
Current code as below:

```js
$scope.memArray = $scope.memberList.split(",");
```

In future I need to split on both comma and newline what should be the regex to split both on comma and newline.
I tried - /,*\n*\ but its not working.

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could replace all the newlines with a comma before splitting.

```
$scope.memberList.replace(/\n/g, ",").split(",")
```

Comment: This would only match the first occurrence of a new line. You'd have to do `.replace(/\n/g, ",")` to replace all occurrences

Comment: @Merott - excellent point

Comment: Thanks that wud also work !!

Comment: It should actually be `.replace(/\r?\n/g, ",")` to handle both unix/mac and windows new lines.

Answer (score 21):

You can use a regex:

```js
var splitted = "a\nb,c,d,e\nf".split(/[\n,]/);
document.write(JSON.stringify(splitted));
```

Explanation: `[...]` defines a "character class", which means any character from those in the brackets.

<sub>p.s. `splitted` is grammatically incorrect. Who cares if it's descriptive though?</sub>

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
.split(/[\n,]+/)
```

this regex should work.

Comment: Yes that wud work but need atleast one or more comma or new line