# How to split a string using white space and "|" in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

My code is`var String = "e-commerce software|mobile"`
And I want to split this string into `e-commerce` `software` `mobile` with only one split sentence. I am not very familiar with regex.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Have you managed to split it on either a space OR a `|` using regex?

Comment: Hi, I mean split it on both space and a |

Comment: I know what you mean. I'm asking how far you have gotten on your own. Have you figured out how to split it on at least one of those? I don't want to just hand out code. I'd rather you understood how to come upon the answer yourself.

Comment: Oh, I know how to split with them either a space OR a | by using string.split() method in javascript

Comment: Here is a good website to help create regexs: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Maybe this? `str.split(/[|\s]+/g)` By the way, it might help you to sit down and really learn regular expressions in the long run. ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
var String = "e-commerce software|mobile";

console.log(String.split(/[\s]|[\|]/));
```

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you can split by one separator doing this:

```
String.split('|');
```

To do the same thing using a regular expression, you could type this:

```
String.split(/\|/);
```

With regular expressions, you can combine single possible expressions using `[]`. So to split on either a space or `|` you could do this:

```
String.split(/[ |\|]/);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use

```
String.split(/[ |]/g)
```