# Javascript how to split() multiple string or values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So for example I want to use the split() method on these characters `"{"` & `"}"` and the string that I'm going to split looks like this `"{99}"`

Comment: @Eddia Please post your actual data

Comment: what do you mean???

Comment: See [ask] & **[mcve]**.

Comment: @EddieCostaDomingues I mean the same as commented by Tushar

Comment: @EddieCostaDomingues Do you want to get string between `{}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to remove those characters or split on those characters to form an array? Your question is confusing and you should consider re-phrasing it.

If you want to remove them:

```js
console.log("{99}".replace(/[{}]/g, "")) /* "99" */
```

If you want to split on them:

```js
console.log("{99}".split(/[{}]/g)) /* ["", "99", ""] */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) method here:

```js
var str = "{99}";

console.log(str.slice(1, -1));
```