# javascript split string multiple ways

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am looking for a way to split a sting like "StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();" into an array with seperate words, symbols and spaces

```
var string = "StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();";
var array = string.split(...);
```

output should be like:

```
array = ["StringBuilder", " ", "SB", " ", "=", " ", "new", " ", "StringBuilder", "(", ")", ";"];
```

Comment: Cool. What have you tried?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: Just write your own tokenizer. char by char..

Comment: @MikeC the most I have tried is basic split(" ") or split(","), im not familiar with more complex methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure this applies all your needs:

```
"StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();".match(/(\s+|\w+|.)/g);
["StringBuilder", " ", "SB", " ", "=", " ", "new", " ", "StringBuilder", "(", ")", ";"]
```

Comment: So this works simply by copy pasting your snippet, but I am curious how "/(\s|\w+|.)/g" this does what it does?

Comment: It just matches tokens by alternation. One of them (`|` separated) should be matched. and if nothing matched last one `.` means "every single character". So, we split input by spaces(`\s+`), words(`\w+`) and other characters(`.`).

Answer (score 1):

easy-customizable solution:

```
function mySplit(str) {
    function isChar(ch) {
        return ch.match(/[a-z]/i);
    }

    var i;
    var result = [];
    var buffer = "";
    var current;
    var onWord = false;

    for (i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
        current = str[i];
        if (isChar(current)) {
            buffer += current;
            onWord = true;
        } else {
            if (onWord) {
                result.push(buffer);
            }
            result.push(current);
            onWord = false;
        }
    }
    if(onWord) {
        result.push(buffer);
    }
    return result;
}
```