# JS how do I select a string from between two special characters?

Tags: javascript, string, substring

I have a string that will be formatted something like `___<test@email.com>____` where the underscores is irrelevant stuff I don't need but varys in length. I need to select and store what is between the brackets.

My problem is that all of the sub string solutions I have seen operate off of a hard integer location in the string. But the start and end of the substring I want to select (the brackets) will never be the same.

So I thought if I could use something to find the location of the brackets then feed that to a substring solution that would work. But all of the ways I have found of identifying special characters only reports if there are special characters, not where they are.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a RegEx, they are the best solution for this kind of problem

Comment: Specifically, _capture groups_ with regex are extremely useful for such "string extraction"

Comment: Thank you you were totally right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

```
var text = '___<test@email.com>____';

var values = text.split(/[<>]+/);

console.log(values); // your values should be at indexes 1, 3, 5, etc...
```

Comment: I've found regex like mine to generally be slower, but yeah, who knows. Either way, nice answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a regex that should set you on your way.

```
let string = "asdf asdf asdf as <thing@stuff.com> jl;kj;l kj ;lkj ;lk j;lk";
let myMatches = string.match(/<.*>/g);
let myMatch = myMatches[0].slice(1).slice(0,-1);
```

The `.match` function returns an array of matches, so you can find multiple `<stuff>` entries.

There's probably a way to do it without the slicing, but that's all I've got for now.

Comment: Thank you! I had heard about regular expressions but never used them till now!

Answer (score 0):

With Regex:

```
var myRe = /<(.*)>/g;
var myArray = myRe.exec("____<asdf>___");
if (myArray)
    console.log(myArray[1]);
```

Regex test [here](https://regex101.com/r/DFG048/1)

JSFiddle test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o0h2p8z9/)