# Webstorm Javascript Regex - Single character alternation in regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to split the string based on two separators like this:

```
"some-str_to_split".split(/-|_/)
```

So it should split the string based on "-" and "_". It works fine, but Webstorming giving a warning:

> Single character alternation in regex

Comment: So what, it is not an error. Surely, `[-_]` is a much better pattern. Both work.

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: The question is if there is something wrong with this approach.

Comment: Nothing is wrong, it is just less efficient than a character class solution.

Comment: So it will be slower?

Comment: It will be a very tiny bit slower in your case.

Comment: Ok understood, it will start to matter if the regex grows bigger, thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Note that `-|_` is a patter that matches `-` or `_`, but each time the regex engine sumbles upon a position in the string, the `-` is tested against first, and if it is not matched, `_` is tried. That involves the so-called backtracking. When you use `[-_]`, a so called [*character class*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), a regex engine uses a compiled mini-program that performs the search faster eliminating the backtracking mechanism.

Thus, the warning is just a kind of a hint for you that your pattern can be enhanced. In case there are 2 chars, the difference in performance is negligeable, if there are 100+ alternatives, the difference will be more tangible.