# Why is JavaScript's split() method not splitting on ":"?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, split

So to start off, a bit of context.  I am pulling data from the following url: "https://webster.cs.washington.edu/pokedex/pokedex.php?pokedex=all" using a GET method.  The data returned is a series of Pokemon names and image names in the following format.

```
Name1:name1.png
Name2:name2.png
...
```

The list is 151 items long.  When I call the typeOf() method "String" is returned, so I am fairly certain it is a String I am dealing with here.  What I would like to do is split the String on the delimiters of "\n" and ":".

What I would like:

```
Name1,name1.png,Name2,name2.png...
```

After some experimentation with Regex, I found that the Regex to do this was "\n|:".  Using this I wrote the following line to split the String apart.  I tested this Regex on https://regex101.com and it seems to work properly there.

```
var splitData = data.split("\n|:");
```

("data" is the String I receive from the url.)

But instead of splitting the String and placing the substrings into an array it doesn't do anything. (At least as far as I can see.)  As such my next idea was to try replacing the characters that were giving me trouble with another character and then splitting on that new character.

```
data = data.replace("\n", " ");
data = data.replace("/:/g", " ");
var splitData = data.split(" ");
```

The first line that replaces new line characters does work, but the second line to replace the ":" does not seem to do anything.  So I end up with an array that is filled with Strings that look like this.

```
Name1:name1.png
```

I can split these strings by calling their index and then splitting the substring stored within, which only confuses me more.

```
data = data.replace("\n", " ");
var splitData = data.split(" ");
alert(splitData[0].split(":")[1]);
```

The above code returns "name1.png".

Am I missing something regarding the split() method?  Is my Regex wrong?  Is there a better way to achieve what I am attempting to do?

Comment: You're not using regexp anywhere in your code. The syntax for regexp is `/regexp/` the syntax for string is `"string"`. You're only using strings

Comment: [Dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/650022/5267751).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you are splitting on the string literal `"\n|:"` but to do a regex you want `data.split(/[:\n]/)`

The [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) shows two ways to build a Regex:

```
var regex1 = /\w+/;
var regex2 = new RegExp('\\w+');
```

Comment: This solved my problem.  Sorry, I'm a bit rusty with Regex (only used it once for a class about a year ago.)  I should do a bit more research on String literals and Regex.  Thanks.

Comment: no problem :) glad to help. Feel free to mark it as the answer if you're satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

The following test script was able to work for me.  I decided to use the regex in the split instead of trying to replace tokens in the string.  It seemed to do the trick for me.

```js
let testResponse = `Abra:abra.png
Aerodactyl:aerodactyl.png`;

let dataArray = testResponse.split(/\n|:/g);
let commaSeperated = dataArray.join(',');

console.log(commaSeperated);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can simply use regex by excluding the quotes all together.

You can look at the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) for regular expressions. They give the following examples:

> `var re = /ab+c/;`
>
> `var re = new RegExp('ab+c');`

See below for your expected output:

```js
var data = `Name1:name1.png
Name2:name2.png`;

var splitData = data.split(/[\n:]/);

console.log(splitData);

//Join them by a comma to get all results
console.log(splitData.join(','));

//For some nice key value pairs, you can reduce the array into an object:

var kvps = data.split("\n").reduce((res, line) => {
  var split = line.split(':');
  return {
      ...res,
      [split[0]]: split[1]
  };
}, {});

console.log(kvps);
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried and this works good.

```
 str.split(/[:\n]/)
```

Here is a plunker.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

Comment: Why create a punker if you can simply embed it in the post?

Comment: I just tried a plunker and thought it would be useful.

Comment: Can someone explain why -1? I do not understand.

Comment: For the record: I'm not the one who downvoted you. Other visitors might find the fact that they have to go off site a worse solution than others. The code snippet tool is there for a reason.

Comment: Thanks @FrankerZ. Makes sense. I tried to provide both simple code here and as well as full working solution in plunkr. But thanks for your suggestion though.