# IGDB API, ionic, angular

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Have anybody an idea, how I can split these in Typescript or JS:

{ "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham", "AFN": "Afghan Afghani", "ALL": "Albanian Lek" }

I want only the names like this:

AED
AFN
ALL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

you are doing it wrong, first of all modify your `object` to `array of objects` like below

```
let currencies = [
  {
    code: "AED",
    fullName: "United Arab Emirates Dirham"

  },
  {
    code: "AFN",
    fullName: "Afghan Afghani"

  },
  {
    code: "ALL",
    fullName: "Albanian Lek"

  }
];
```

now you can traverse through it like

```
currencies.forEach(val => {
  //use val.code to get desired currencies codes
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)) to extract all keys from some object.

```
var countries = { "AED": "United Arab Emirates Dirham", "AFN": "Afghan Afghani", "ALL": "Albanian Lek" }
var codes = Object.keys( countries );
console.log( codes ); // [ "AED", "AFN", "ALL" ]
```