# Split string based on array of characters in array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have ab array something like this :

```
const operators = ['<','>','>=','<>','=']
```

and a string something like this :

```
const myStr = 'Some Operand > Some Other Operand'
```

as you see in this string I have `>` character that exists in operator array now I want to split string base on operators characters that exisits in array. I know I can do this with regex but i can't figure how to do it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I update my question but that's just for knowing is split or anyone do this before.

Comment: Without regex: `operators.reduce((sum, op) => [].concat(...sum.map((str) => str.split(op))), [myStr])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in regex with the vertical bar: `(<|>|>=|<>|=)`, this will match one of the specified patterns (your operators).

And you can pass a regex to the [`split()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```js
function f(s) { return s.split(/(<>|>=|>|<|=)/); }
console.log(f("Some Operand > Some Other Operand"));
console.log(f("Some Operand >= Some Other Operand"));
```

*Edit:* inside the regex above, I wrote the 2-character operators first, then the single-character ones. This way, it will match all operators correctly. You can even simplify the regex by using [optionals](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html):

```js
function f(s) { return s.split(/(<>?|>=?|=)/); }
console.log(f("Some Operand > Some Other Operand"));
console.log(f("Some Operand >= Some Other Operand"));
```

If you're interested in doing this without regex, you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976348/2418224) which uses `split` and `join` functions.

Comment: *"Note that I have added space around the operator pattern, so you don't need to trim the operands."* Two issues: 1. It's fairly unusual to **require** spaces around operators, and 2. This doesn't mean OP doesn't have to trim, because it doesn't handle multiple spaces.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks. Since the original post doesn't mention spaces/trimming, I'll remove it from my answer too.

Comment: @juzraai after removing space if string contain `>=` it splits with `>` how do I exactly if string contains `>=` with `>=` and not `>`

Comment: Oh I see. Please see my edited answer. I changed the order of the operators inside the regex. Also I provided a simplified pattern.