# Split string by any 3 options (newline, comma, white space) in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox that the users can copy/paste string data into. This is going to be a string of numbers. This string of numbers could be copied/pasted from a csv string, a string separated by space, or separated by newline. So ideally I'd be able to handle all 3 (or more separators in the future).

Currently I have the below code but I just get an array of empty strings when I copy/paste from all 3 scenarios:

```
var data = event.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain').split(/[\n,\S+]/);
```

It seems to be the \S+ that causes the issue. If I just have \n, it works for both /n and commas but as soon as I add the \S+ it gives all empty strings for everything.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: `\s+`, not `\S+`  : `console.log(\`1,2,3,4,5,6
7 8 9 10\`.split(/[\n,\s+]/))`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @mplungjan So what's interesting with that is if the commas have a space after them like "25, 64, 57" I end up with elements in the array that is empty strings. Same thing happens with the /n copy/paste from excel. After each number I get 2 empty string elements in the array.

Comment: Please see my adjusted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\s+` not `\S+`  and get rid of whitespace after a comma

```js
var str = `1,2,3,4,5, 6, 7
8 9 10`

console.log(str.replace(/,\s+/g,",").split(/[\n,\s+]/))
```

Comment: underrated answer. good looking out.