# Insert backspace in regex in camelCased JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, backspace

I have a string in JavaScript and at some places corresponding to a regex (lower case followed by upper case), I would like to insert between upper and lower case the backspace character.

This is an example:

> Manufacturer: SamsungWarranty: 12 monthsUnlocking: Any operatorIris scanner: NoScreen size: 5.7 inchesDisplay resolution: 2560 x 1440 pixels

It should become:

```
Manufacturer: Samsung

Warranty: 12 months

Unlocking: Any operator

Iris scanner: No

Screen size: 5.7 inches

Display resolution: 2560 x 1440 pixels
```

Comment: Where is the string you need to parse, we would need the string and the desired outcome

Comment: This kind of string
"FooFooFoo"
I would like this to become
"Foo
Foo
Foo" 
Insert backspace within o and F

Comment: You can `split` at each case your regex match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: How can i split ? With which regex.
This is a better example

Manufacturer: SamsungWarranty: 12 monthsUnlocking: Any operatorIris scanner: NoScreen size: 5.7 inchesDisplay resolution: 2560 x 1440 pixels

It should become

Manufacturer: Samsung
Warranty: 12 months
Unlocking: Any operator
Iris scanner: No
Screen size: 5.7 inches
Display resolution: 2560 x 1440 pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match on `/([a-z])([A-Z])/g` and replace with `"$1\n\n$2"`, then prepend `"Manufacturer: "` to the beginning of the string.

```js
const s = "SamsungWarranty: 12 monthsUnlocking: Any operatorIris scanner: NoScreen size: 5.7 inchesDisplay resolution: 2560 x 1440 pixels";
const res = "Manufacturer: " + s.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, "$1\n\n$2");
console.log(res);
```