# How split multiple characters with javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello I have a string and I want to split some characters from it like: space, comma and "`;`". Normally I'm splitting on the comma from such a string:

```
myText.split(',')
```

But I want to split on *any* of these 3 characters? For example, if the string is `"cat dog,fox;cow fish"` the result will be the array `["cat", "dog", "fox", "cow", "fish"]`.

how to do that?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead, with a character set containing `[ ,;]`:

```js
const str = 'foo bar;baz,buzz'
console.log(str.split(/[ ,;]/));
```

Or you could `.match` characters that are not any of those:

```js
const str = 'foo bar;baz,buzz'
console.log(str.match(/[^ ,;]+/g));
```