# use a split function in Javascript, on string which is already split

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I need to split the already split string.

For example,

```
String 1= "This,is, my, problem;I, need,a, solution";
```

Now I need to split the first sentence based on ";" and once I get this string, which should give me 2 sentences

> 1 "This,is,my,problem"
>
> 2 "I,need,a,solution"

And I need to further split these two sentences based on ",".

> This
>
> is
>
> my
>
> problem
>
> I
>
> need
>
> a
>
> solution

Is this possible using JavaScript.When I am trying to split the two sentences, I am getting error in JavaScript.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. Show us what you tried, instead of just telling us that you “get errors.”

Comment: `str.split(';').map(s => s.split(',')).flat()`

Comment: `string.split(/,|;/)`

Comment: Please try this https://stackblitz.com/edit/string-split-map?file=index.js

Comment: please try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You need a combination of `.map` and `.split`.

```js
var x = "This,is, my, problem;I, need,a, solution";

var op = x
        .split(";") // first split
        .map(el => el
                  .split(",") // second split
                  .map(el => el.trim())) // to remove the begining and end space
        .flat(1); // to flatten the array by 1 level

console.log(op);
```

Comment: Thank you Archie, let me try and I will keep you posted.