# String Splitting with multiple delimiters in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, date, split

How to split strings of format like "12-12-1990" or "12/12/1990" where - and / are the delimiters.
I have seen answers  using regex but I am not proficient in it. Answers regarding this will be helpful as I am a beginner

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Comment: I am unable to understand answers there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
"2020-01-31".split(/[/-]/ig)
```

```js
var dateParts1 = "2020-01-31".split(/[/-]/ig);
console.log(dateParts1);


var dateParts2 = "2020/02/21".split(/[/-]/ig);
console.log(dateParts2);
```

Regex explain
[image]

Comment: Why `i` modifier? Are you expecting these chars to be uppercased?

Comment: not important but he said that he is not an expert in regex, so I put it if he need to add more chars or other example

Comment: what to do if i want both the delimiters in a single expression

Comment: the above expression do this in single one, see the explain of regex

Comment: what is i and g in the regex

Comment: **i flag**: With this flag the search is case-insensitive: no difference between A and a

Comment: **g flag**: With this flag the search looks for all matches, without it – only the first match is returned.

Comment: for more see https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a regex into Javascript's split operator. For example:

```
"12-12-1990".split(/-|\//) 
["12", "12", "1990"]

"12/12/1990".split(/-|\//) 
["12", "12", "1990"]
```

Comment: `String#split` isn't an operator

Answer (score -1):

You can use split with the delimiter on which you want to split the string

```js
var x="12-12-1990";
console.log(x.split('-'))
```

Comment: I don't think you're fully answering the question