# issue with splitting multiple characters

Tags: javascript, split

I have sentences like

> Cash is king. The day you prepared the accounting plan, I was sure that you will draft the accounting standards carefully and our accounts will not required to be window dressed. Sir you write the narration.

and I want to split this sentence with `?` and `.`

for that I have used

```
var words= 'Cash is king. The day you prepared the accounting plan, I was sure that you will draft the accounting standards carefully and our accounts will not be required to be window dressed. Sir you write the narration.';
var split = words.split(".");

console.log(split);
```

it is working but I want to split the sentence with `?` and `.` both at the same time.  How can I do that?

can anybody help me with this

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Comment: Note that string manipulation is javascript not jquery, I've updated the tags+question slightly to reflect this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split on both `?` and `.` at the same time using the regular expression format of `.split()`, ie:

```
words.split(/[?.]/)
```

Example snippet:

```js
var test = "abc?def.ghi";
var parts = test.split(/[?.]/)
console.log(parts)
```