# How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript without using regexp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this string

```
let str = "name1,name2/name3"
```

and I want to split on "," and "/", is there is a way to split it without using regexp?

this is the desire output

```
name1
name2
name3
```

Comment: *'...without using regexp'* may I ask: why?

Comment: This has been answered before check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36976348/13331933

Comment: I have data with a lot of different separators, and I was wondering if there is cleaner way to split it, like using "or" or something like that

Answer (score 1):

Little bit of a circus but gets it done:

```
let str = "name1,name2/name3";
str.split("/").join(",").split(",");
```

Convert all the characters you want to split by to one character and do a `split` on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can split first by `,`, then convert to array again and split again by `/`

```js
str.split(",").join("/").split("/")
```

Answer (score 0):

Without regexp you can use this trick

```
str.split('/').join(',').split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .split() method:

```
const names = "name1,name2/name3".split(/[,\/]/);
```

You still have to use a regex literal as the token to split on, but not regex methods specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Just get imaginative with `String.spit()`.

```js
let str = "name1,name2/name3";
let str1 = str.split(",");
let str2 = str1[1].split("/");
let result = [str1[0],str2[0],str2[1]];
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex you can use this function:

```js
function split (str, seps) {
  sep1 = seps.pop();
  seps.forEach(sep => {
    str = str.replace(sep, sep1);
  })
  return str.split(sep1);
}
```

usage:

```js
const separators = [',', ';', '.', '|', ' '];
const myString = 'abc,def;ghi jkl';

console.log(split(myString, separators));
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use regexp:

```js
"name1,name2/name3".split(/,|;| |\//);
```

this will split by `,`, `;`,  or `/`

or

```js
 "name1,name2/name3".split(/\W/)
```

this will split by any non alphanumeric char

Comment: "...split it without using regexp?"