# Split multiline text by space and line break

Tags: javascript, string, split

Can you pass several options as the argument to `.split`? Trying to get or/and behavior.

Comment: Using a regex: `"abc 444\n555".split(/\s|\n/)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Comment: @wiomoc `\s|\n` is redundant: `\s` already includes `\n`. You may have meant `( |\n)` or `[ \n]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

```js
`Hello World!\nBye World!`.split(/ |\n/); // ["Hello", "World!", "Bye", "World!"]
```