# JS using OR in string split

Tags: javascript, date, split

I have CSV with dates in format DD-MM-YYYY but sometimes I work in Excel and it changes the dates to format DD/MM/YYYY

Code example

```
var dateParts = value['TAX_CALCULATION_DATE'].split("/"); //id date has "-" or "/"
var dateObject = new Date(+dateParts[2], dateParts[1] - 1, +dateParts[0]);
firestoreObject.TAX_CALCULATION_DATE = firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(dateObject);
```

How to include "/" and "-" in one split?

Comment: [How do I split a string with multiple separators in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/650022)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex in split;

```
// Matches / or -
const regex = /\/|-/g;
yourDate.split(regex);
```