# Regex to match string inside curly braces inside square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var q = '{[{main}(other data)][{data}(other data)][{address}(other data)]}';

var qm = q.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);  

console.log(qm);
```

The above regex returns text that's between parenthesis.

**Eg:**

```
 [{data}(other data)]
```

How can the above Regex be rewritten so I supplied a string like `'data'` it would return `[{data}(other data)]`. i.e the part with parenthesis that contains the string in curly braces.

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: What other way are you suggesting?

Comment: Use [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/650037/102937) to get an array of elements surrounded by brackets.  Once you have the array, it should be a simple matter to search each element for the desired string.

Comment: You need to use a regex constructor, like 'var regex = new RegExp('\\[\\{' + 'data' + '\\}[^\\]]+\\]'); Replace 'data' with your variable to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matches string inside the curly brace

```
\[{data}\(.*?*\)\]
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ducMKk/1)**

```js
var q = '{[{main}(other data)][{data}(other data)][{address}(other data)]}';

var qm = (str) => q.match(new RegExp(`\\[{${str}}\\(.*?\\)\\]`, 'g'));

console.log(qm('data'));
```

Matches string inside the curly brace and parenthesis

```
\[{data}\(.*?data[^)]*\)\]
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DJ5Yee/1)**

```js
var q = '{[{main}(other data)][{data}(other data)][{address}(other data)]}';

var qm = (str) => q.match(new RegExp(`\\[{${str}}\\(.*?${str}[^)]*\\)\\]`, 'g'));

console.log(qm('data'));
```

Comment: What is the `${str}` in your code? Is it a Regex Literal or Template Literal. Do older version of IE support this?

Comment: @jmenezes Its a template literal. For browser support, you can concat as normal string

Comment: I'm using your first code snippet. Any idea how I can get the results without the `[` `]` in the result. So instead of `[{data}(other data)]` it'll be `{data}(other data)` (no square brackets). If it's possible i'll post another question.

Answer (score 0):

Using your `qm` variable, you can iterate over the matches and test for the string between the first curly braces like so:

```js
var q = '{[{main}(other data)][{data}(other data)][{address}(other data)]}';
var qm = q.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g);

for (let e of qm)
  if (e.match('\{([^\)]+)\}')[1] == "data")
    console.log(e);
```