# Transform string intro array using Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

I was wondering if is possible to transform a string into an array using Arrow Function:

```
var str = 'Bob@example.com;Mark@example.com,robert@email.com';

var result = str.split(';').map(e => e.split(','))

//desired result: {VALUE: 'Bob@example.com'},
//                {VALUE: 'Mark@example.com},
//                {VALUE: 'robert@email.com'}
```

Comment: Does [How do I split a string with multiple separators in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript) help?

Comment: `Mark@example.com` and `robert@email.com` aren't separated by a semi-colon.

Comment: Replace each , with ; then complete your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could split with a character class of comma and semicolon and map objects.

```js
const
    str = 'Bob@example.com;Mark@example.com,robert@email.com',
    result = str
        .split(/[,;]/)
        .map(VALUE => ({ VALUE }));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina, in case to pass two values like:
{VALUE_type: 'work', value_email:'Bob@example.com'},

I can use this map?

Comment: do you have always the same type?

Comment: Yes.. the same structure for all emails
//desired result: {"VALUE_TYPE": "WORK", "VALUE":'Bob@example.com'},
//      {"VALUE_TYPE": "WORK", "VALUE":'Mark@example.com},
//      {"VALUE_TYPE": "WORK", "VALUE": 'robert@email.com'}

Comment: take a variable `VALUE_TYPE = "WORK"` and `.map(VALUE => ({ VALUE_TYPE ,VALUE }))`.

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to handle this

```js
var str = 'Bob@example.com;Mark@example.com,robert@email.com';

var result = str.split(/[;,]/)

console.log(result);
```