# Split multiple text (Dynamically) in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, for-loop

Here I have text something like this:

1. `const string = 'Welcome;;to::';`
2. `const string ='Welcome;;';`

I want to split this string with `;;` and `::`;

Expected result:
`['Welcome', ';;', 'to', '::']`

There will be chance that number of pattern will be increased.
So, is this possible ?

**Note:** There is no space between words.

Comment: Split by non-word characters and use a capturing group so it's included in the resulting array

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650022/how-do-i-split-a-string-with-multiple-separators-in-javascript

Comment: result = string.split(";;").join(" ;; ").split("::").join(" ::").split(" ");

Comment: or result = string.replace(";;", " ;; ").replace("::", " ::").split(" "); You basically need to insert spaces around the delimiters and perform a final split to remove them.

Comment: `let arr = 'Welcome;;to::'.match(/\w+|\W+/g)`

Comment: @Dave Pritlove If it's dynamic then how to split then ? Like if in this case there is two pattern (;;, ::) now if it has three then how to handle dynamically ?

Comment: if there's always no spaces, you would simply pass each delimeter to `replace("xx", " xx ")` to insert the spaces before the final split on " ". If the string ends with a delimiter, as your example is, you'll have to only insert the space behind it (or remove the resulting  element at the end of the array afterwards).